# AWS Signature Creation. Confused on how to covert the SigningKey and SingingString into Signature. AWS Example Seems To Not Yield Expected Result

Tags: amazon-web-services, signature, hmac, signing

I'm trying to write my own AWS4 signer, and I've gotten about 2/3 of the way there. Source code here :

```
public class Test
{
    private static String region = "us-east-1";
    static byte[] HmacSHA256(String data, byte[] key) throws Exception {
        String algorithm="HmacSHA256";
        Mac mac = Mac.getInstance(algorithm);
        mac.init(new SecretKeySpec(key, algorithm));
        return mac.doFinal(data.getBytes("UTF8"));
    }

public static byte[] justSha256(String data) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
    MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
    byte[] hash = digest.digest(data.getBytes("UTF8"));
    return hash;
}

static byte[] getSigningKey(String key, String dateStamp, String regionName, String serviceName) throws Exception {
    byte[] kSecret = ("AWS4" + key).getBytes("UTF8");


    byte[] kDate = HmacSHA256(dateStamp, kSecret);

    byte[] kRegion = HmacSHA256(regionName, kDate);

    byte[] kService = HmacSHA256(serviceName, kRegion);

    byte[] kSigning = HmacSHA256("aws4_request", kService);

    return kSigning;
}



public static String getSimpleDate()
{
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("YYYYMMdd");


    return LocalDate.now().format(formatter);
}

public static String getAMZDate()
{
/*DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("YYYYMMDDHHMMSS");
String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("YYMMDD'T'HHMMSS'Z'").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());*/


    TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC");
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmss'Z'"); // Quoted "Z" to indicate UTC, no timezone offset
    df.setTimeZone(tz);
    String timeStamp = df.format(new Date());


    return timeStamp;
}



public static String createSigningString(String timeStamp, String simpleDate,String serviceName) throws UnsupportedEncodingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException {

  /*AWS4-HMAC-SHA256
  20150830T123600Z
  20150830/us-east-1/iam/aws4_request
  f536975d06c0309214f805bb90ccff089219ecd68b2577efef23edd43b7e1a59*/

    String algorithm = "AWS4-HMAC-SHA256\n";
    String amzDate = timeStamp+"\n";
    String simpleDateRegionServiceRequest = simpleDate+"/"+region+"/"+serviceName+"/"+"aws4_request\n";

    String canonicalHash = getCanonicalHash(getCanonicalString("GET","/","Action=ListUsers&Version=2010-05-08","20150830T123600Z",""));

    String signingString = algorithm+amzDate+simpleDateRegionServiceRequest+canonicalHash;



    return signingString;

}

public static String getCanonicalString(String method, String absolutePath, String queryString, String timeStamp, String payload) throws UnsupportedEncodingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException {

    String contentType = "Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8\n".toLowerCase();
    String hostUrl = "host:iam.amazonaws.com\n";
    String date = "x-amz-date:"+timeStamp+"\n";

    String signedHeader = "content-type;host;x-amz-date\n";

    String hashedPayload = Hex.encodeHexString(justSha256(payload)).toLowerCase();



    String canonicalString = method+"\n"+absolutePath+"\n"+queryString+"\n"+contentType+hostUrl+date+"\n"+signedHeader+hashedPayload;




    return canonicalString;
}


public static String getCanonicalHash(String canonicalString) throws UnsupportedEncodingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException {
    return Hex.encodeHexString(justSha256(canonicalString)).toLowerCase();
}




public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {


    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("YYYYMMDDHHMMSS");
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYYMMDD'T'HHMMSS'Z'").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());


    String canonString;
    System.out.println( canonString = getCanonicalHash(getCanonicalString("GET","/","Action=ListUsers&Version=2010-05-08","20150830T123600Z","")));

    String signingString = createSigningString("20150830T123600Z","20150830","iam");

    String key = "wJalrXUtnFEMI/K7MDENG+bPxRfiCYEXAMPLEKEY";
    String dateStamp = "20120215";
    String regionName = "us-east-1";
    String serviceName = "iam";

    String signingKey = Hex.encodeHexString(getSigningKey(key,dateStamp,regionName,serviceName));

    SoftAssertions softly = new SoftAssertions();

    softly.assertThat(canonString).isEqualToIgnoringCase("f536975d06c0309214f805bb90ccff089219ecd68b2577efef23edd43b7e1a59");
    String copiedSigningString = "AWS4-HMAC-SHA256\n" +
            "20150830T123600Z\n" +
            "20150830/us-east-1/iam/aws4_request\n" +
            "f536975d06c0309214f805bb90ccff089219ecd68b2577efef23edd43b7e1a59";



    softly.assertThat(signingString).isEqualTo(copiedSigningString);



    softly.assertThat(signingKey).isEqualToIgnoringCase("f4780e2d9f65fa895f9c67b32ce1baf0b0d8a43505a000a1a9e090d414db404d");

    dateStamp ="20150830";

    signingKey = Hex.encodeHexString(getSigningKey(key,dateStamp,regionName,serviceName));

    softly.assertThat(signingKey).isEqualToIgnoringCase("c4afb1cc5771d871763a393e44b703571b55cc28424d1a5e86da6ed3c154a4b9");


    System.out.println("COPIED STRING : "+copiedSigningString);

    System.out.println("SIGNING KEY : "+signingKey);
    String signature = Hex.encodeHexString(HmacSHA256(signingKey.trim(),justSha256(copiedSigningString)));

    System.out.println("Signature : "+signature);

    softly.assertThat(signature).isEqualToIgnoringCase("5d672d79c15b13162d9279b0855cfba6789a8edb4c82c400e06b5924a6f2b5d7");

    softly.assertAll();

}
```

}

For some reason I'm failing to create the correct Signature. Which is created by using the SigningKey and SingingString as input into an HMACSha256 function, specifically the function highlighted on this page https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signature-v4-examples.html#signature-v4-examples-java.

But for some reason, I cannot produce the signature that AWS says will be created here on this page.: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sigv4-calculate-signature.html
(5d672d79c15b13162d9279b0855cfba6789a8edb4c82c400e06b5924a6f2b5d7)

Despite using their function, their Strings as input, and double checking my work. What am I missing?

Are you supposed to use a different function for these Strings or byte[]?

I feel like I'm missing something, and I don't know where to reconcle this confusion because from my code and what I see on these pages I seem to be doing the right thing.

I'm especially confused because when I pasted the String from their site into my code to see if it would convert properly it did not, despite using their same Hmac function (which did work for creating every other hash string posted on their site).

Answer (score 1):

The hex representation of the date, region, service, and signing keys is shown for illustration, because the keys contain bytes that do not represent printable characters.

But you appear to be hex-encoding your signing key before using it to sign the request.  Don't do that.  You will want to hex-encode it only for viewing/debugging.  The actual signing key should be retained and used in its original binary/byte form.

> Use the digest (binary format) for the key derivation. Most languages have functions to compute either a binary format hash, commonly called a digest, or a hex-encoded hash, called a hexdigest. The key derivation requires that you use a binary-formatted digest.
>
> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sigv4-calculate-signature.html

The canonical request hash in the string-to-sign is used in hex-encoded form, as is the final signature.  The key derivation is all binary.

Comment: You're right. I made the mistake of mixing up variables, and making the improper assumption that values would be preserved between conversions.